# Proof for a statement on prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I read the following statement:

> We can define the number $$x=2^0\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^2\cdot 7^3\cdot\ldots\cdot b^n$$ where $b$ is the $n$'th prime number. That is, $b$ is the $n$'th prime number if and only if there is some $x<b^{2n}$ that can be factored as above and has $b^n$ but not $b^{n+1}$ as a factor.

It's not immediately obvious to me how $x<b^{2n}$ (but maybe there's something I'm not seeing properly). How would one prove this inequality?

**EDIT:** It has come to my attention that the initial statement was $x<{b^n}^2$, which was meant to be read as $x<b^{(n^2)}$ and not as $x<\left(b^n\right)^2$ (the way I used in this question).

Comment: Try using induction on n (starting at n=1, because it doesn't actually work for 0)

Comment: @Robert That's the first thing I did, but I run into some trouble, since we need to introduce a new prime number for the $n+1$ step. Also, this is not a homework question, so please feel free to type up a complete answer if you have one.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense. I'd try some experiments, see whether it's really true that, say, $3\cdot5^2\cdot\dots\cdot109^{27}$ is less than $109^{54}$.

Comment: turns out induction isn't as straightforward as it looks

Comment: Is it a property of this number that the indices are increasing by 1 each time? If so, then surely it should $...{b^{n-1}}$. Unless we are saying that 2 is the zeroth prime...

Comment: The claim is incorrect. When $n=4$,
$$2^03^15^27^311^4=19.746\ldots$$
while
$$11^8=19.183\ldots$$

Further arguments can be made with the prime number theorem: $p_n\sim n\ln(n)$. Notice that
$$\ln(x)>\sum_{k=1}^n k=\Omega(n^2),$$
while $\ln(p_n^{2n})\sim 2n\ln(n\ln(n))=o(n^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'd like to apologize for making a mistake in the question - then again, the original formulation in the text was ambiguous. The edited property is now easy to prove.

For $n>1$, we have that $$\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}<n^2.$$
Therefore: $$x=2^0\cdot 3^1\cdot 5^2\cdot\ldots\cdot b^n<b^0\cdot b^1\cdot b^2\cdot\ldots \cdot b^{n-1}\cdot b^n=b^{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} i}<b^{(n^2)}$$